# Vue JS ternary expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm using Vue JS and am trying to use a ternary expression to conditionally change the value of something, I'm struggling with how to convert the following to a ternary expression, here's my method, by default: `isLoading` is true

```js
fetchData(showLoading) {
  if (showLoading) {
    this.isLoading = true
  } else {
    this.isLoading = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the conditional operator here, just assign `showLoading` to `isLoading`, assuming you're passing a boolean:

```
this.isLoading = showLoading;
```

If you're not necessarily passing a boolean, then cast to boolean first (if needed):

```
this.isLoading = Boolean(showLoading);
```

If you *had* to use the conditional operator, it would be:

```
this.isLoading = showLoading ? true : false;
```

Comment: That's what the `Boolean` is for (which I personally prefer over `!!` since it's more explicit)

Answer (score 1):

```
fetchData(showLoading) {
 showLoading ? (this.isLoading = true) : (this.isLoading = false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your 'showLoading' data is I guess Boolean and you dont need if else.

```
this.isLoading = showLoading
```

and it's wrong below code will get error

```
this.isLoading = showLoading ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to force showLoading to be a Boolean so try this

```
this.isLoading = !!showLoading;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.showLoading = isLoading ? true : false;
```